# Rails 4 - Pre-Populate Form From Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form that allows users to manually input movies to review.  Additionally, I am pulling movies from an external API (TMDB).  When the user searches, it shows all results from the database as well as another area where data is pulled from the API.  I want them to be able to click on a thumbnail from the external API and pre-populate my "new" form with that data.  This code currently goes to the "new" form, but the title and description are not populated like I want them to be (a blank new form is rendered).

```
<% if @movies_api %>
<div class="row">
  <% @movies_api.each do |movie| %>
    <% if movie.poster_path %>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <%= link_to(image_tag('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w396' + movie.poster_path, class: 'image', size:"400x600"), {:action => 'new', :controller => 'movies'}, :title => movie.title, :description => movie.overview ) if movie.poster_path %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How do I accomplish pre-populating the new form with data I gather from the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this.  In my form, I can do:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title, :value => params[:title] %>
  </div>
```

Not sure if there is a better way, but this works :-)